# Using slidingmenu(jfeinstein10),how could know if the slidingmenu is shown(some method don't take effect)

Tags: android, slidingmenu

Using slidingmenu(jfeinstein10),how could know if the slidingmenu is shown(some method don't take effect).
I want to know the status of the slidingmenu ,I have already tried:

```
        Log.d("slidingMenu.isShown()", slidingMenu.isShown()+"");
        Log.d("slidingMenu.isShown()", slidingMenu.getVisibility()+"");
        Log.d("slidingMenu.isShown()", slidingMenu.isActivated()+"");
        Log.d("slidingMenu.hasFocus()", slidingMenu.hasFocus()+"");
        Log.d("slidingMenu.hasFocusable()", slidingMenu.hasFocusable()+"");
        Log.d("slidingMenu.hasWindowFocus()", slidingMenu.hasWindowFocus()+"");
        Log.d("slidingMenu.isActivated()", slidingMenu.isActivated()+"");
        Log.d("slidingMenu.isClickable()", slidingMenu.isClickable()+"");
        Log.d("slidingMenu.isEnabled();", slidingMenu.isEnabled()+"");
        Log.d("slidingMenu.isFocusable()", slidingMenu.isFocusable()+"");
        Log.d("slidingMenu.isFocused()", slidingMenu.isFocused()+"");
        Log.d("slidingMenu.isSlidingEnabled()", slidingMenu.isSlidingEnabled()+"");
        Log.d("slidingMenu.isSelected()", slidingMenu.isSelected()+"");
```

But no matter the menufragment is shown or gone,these methods return the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Line 550 in `SlidingMenu.java`](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/library/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib/SlidingMenu.java#L550):

```
/**
 * Checks if is the behind view showing.
 *
 * @return Whether or not the behind view is showing
 */
public boolean isMenuShowing() {
    return mViewAbove.getCurrentItem() == 0 || mViewAbove.getCurrentItem() == 2;
}
```